# How can I update the page title in Google Analytics Report screens using dataLayer and Google Tag Manager?

Tags: next.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, next.js13

[GA4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6KXY.png)

I want to influence the page titles that appear in Google Analytics reports, such as changing "Pakete" to "Pakete | Turkey - Antalya - Hotel" when user search parameters are triggered on the website and the URL changes.. After doing some research, I heard that this can be done through dataLayer in Google Tag Manager, but I couldn't find the exact method. Could someone inform me about this?

I have created these in Tag Manager.

[I have created these in Tag Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pZbr.png)

[I have created these in Tag Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agsZ9.png)

and I added these in html head tag in nextjs. ->

`<script> dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'virtualPageview', 'virtualPageURL': window.location.pathname, 'virtualPageTitle': document.title }); </script>`

**What specific dataLayer variable should be used to capture the page title for Google Analytics?
**How can the dataLayer variable for the page title be configured in Google Tag Manager?
**What steps are required to update the page title in Google Analytics using the dataLayer and Google Tag Manager?
**Are there any best practices or considerations to keep in mind when implementing this solution?
**How can the updated page title be verified in Google Analytics after implementing the dataLayer and Google Tag Manager solution?